# Odoo ir.rule domain_force for group role depend on state

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, access-rights

I have 3 group roles: user, manager and logist. And need that user and manager on states 'approved', and 'to_approve_second' do not have write right.

all the users have write right and there are ir.rules:

```
    <field name="name">Follow Purchase Request</field>

    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>

    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_user')])]"/>

    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>

    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>

    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>

    <field name="domain_force">['|',('requested_by','=',user.id),

                                    ('message_partner_ids', 'in', [user.partner_id.id])]</field>

</record>



<record id="purchase_request_rule" model="ir.rule">

    <field name="name">Purchase Request User</field>

    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>

    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_user')])]"/>

    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>

    <field name="domain_force">[('requested_by','=',user.id)]</field>

</record>



<record id="purchase_request_manager_rule" model="ir.rule">

    <field name="name">Purchase Request Manager</field>

    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>

    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_manager')])]"/>

    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>

</record>
```

I tried to add:

```
    <field name="name">Purchase Request User Rule</field>

    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>

    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_user')])]"/>

    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>

    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>

    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>

    <field name="domain_force">[('state','in',('approved', 'to_approve_second'))]</field>

</record>
```

```
    <field name="name">Purchase Request Manager Rule</field>

    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>

    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_manager')])]"/>

    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>

    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>

    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>

    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>

    <field name="domain_force">[('state','in',('approved', 'to_approve_second'))]</field>

</record>
```

But nothing happens. User and manager can edit the document on  'approved' and 'to_approve_second' states.
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works!

```
<record id="purchase_request_followers_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Follow Purchase Request</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_user')])]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">['|',('requested_by','=',user.id),
                                    ('message_partner_ids', 'in', [user.partner_id.id])]</field>
</record>

<record id="purchase_request_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Purchase Request User</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_user')])]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('requested_by','=',user.id)]</field>
</record>

<record id="no_edit_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">No Edit Rule</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_user')])]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('requested_by','=',user.id),('state','not in',('approved', 'to_approve_second'))]
```

```
<record id="purchase_request_manager_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Purchase Request Manager</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_manager')])]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('assigned_to','=',user.id),('state','in',('to_approve_first', 'create_order'))]
```

```
<record id="manager_manager_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Manager manager</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_request"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(6,0, [ref('group_purchase_request_manager')])]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('assigned_to','=',user.id)]</field>
</record>
```